# Secure API access: best strategy to secure readonly rails api for android client

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, api, ssl, heroku

I have developed a readonly api using ruby on rails, also developed an android client for this api.

What I want is to restrict access to this readonly api.

What is the best possible solution I can use for my api,

1. Use HTTP Basic Authentication
2. Authentication Via an Access Token
3. OAuth etc.

Do I need an ssl certificate?

My rails API is hosted on heroku. Should i use app.herokuapp.com subdomain ssl or use my custom domain and purchase ssl certificate for my custom domain.

If I do need an ssl certificate, please suggest best possible and cheapest provider for ssl certificate.

thanks in advance!

Comment: The most secure way to go is require client to present server supplied vertificate. I'm not entirely sure how this works, but over https you can ask client for cert (I think sth similiar to ssl). This gives you possibility to revoke auth for some users violating your api terms.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure method for APIs is to give each user a different authentication token for API. On the other hand, if you want to make it even **more** secure, I personally suggest you a SSL, because SSL encrypts the packages between server and client, therefore it will be impossible (not impossible but near impossible depending on your SSL certificate) to hijack the communications between server and client.

Comment: As of now I don't want my app users to sign up or go through a registration step. How can I give each user a different authentication token without sign up?

Comment: Find a method to differentiate each user from another. For example IP. But an ip can have multiple users in it, so not a good solution. After you find out what that differentiation is, parse that information and put it into a SHA2-256 hash with a SALT, and use that as a token.

Comment: On the other hand, if there isn't any registration step, a simple authentication for every user will be enough. Just limit the capabilities of the API. For example, in API's format, make sure that it doesn't give out any sensitive information to the end user.